# Linq - Left outer join with dot notation

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

How would I do a left outer join in linq using dot notation?

Here's the query expression:

```
var query = from u in db.Users
            join d in db.Defects on u.userID equals d.userID into defectsGroup
            from d in defectsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { u, d };
```

Here's what I tried:

```
var query2 = db.Users.GroupJoin(db.Defects.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                u => u.userID, 
                d => d.userID, 
                (user, defect) => new { user, defect });
```

But defect is showing as `IEnumerable<Defect>` rather than just `Defect`.  I also tried:

```
var query2 = db.Users.GroupJoin(db.Defects, 
                u => u.userID, 
                d => d.userID, 
                (user, defect) => new { user, defect.DefaultIfEmpty() });
```

Which simply doesn't compile.  All the online examples seem to use the (clearer) query syntax.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
var query2 = db.Users.GroupJoin(db.Defects,
                                u => u.userId,
                                d => d.userID,
                                (u, defectsGroup) => new { u, defectsGroup})
                     .SelectMany(z => z.defectsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                                 (z, d) => new { z.u, d });
```

See my [Edulinq blog post on query expressions](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/) for more details.

Comment: Wow - I guess that's why all the samples use query syntax for that :)

Comment: @Adam: Yeah, joins are rather simpler in query syntax :)

Comment: all the documentation I can find at Microsoft on DefaultIfEmpty says (and the examples show) that it returns an enumeration of one default item when the given enumeration is empty.  Left outer join examples all show that it returns a default item when the PARTICULAR item in an enumeration is null.  I see that this works, but where is the doc for this particular (apparently different) method?  THANKS!

Comment: @Kelly: I'm not sure what you mean. The point is that GroupJoin will end up with an empty group "on the right" when there are no matches for the "left" element. SelectMany is then pairing each "left" entry with a "right" entry - but using a "right" entry of null if the group is empty.